# Wrap each word in string with characters using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

## Goal

I am attempting to create a function that takes a string as an argument and wraps each individual word within the string with double quotes and returns that as a string.

## Attempted

What I tried is the below sed snippet, but it outputted the whole string wrapped in double quotes instead of each individual word.
`sed -r "s/ /\"/g"`

## Expect

```bash
function wordWrapper {
  # Do some magic here
}

var = wordWrapper "Hello World"
echo $var
```

should output `"Hello" "World"`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do post some samples of input and expected output in your question that will make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: `sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+/"&"/g' file > newfile`

Comment: The command `s/ /"/g` (the sed command that is, after parsing by the shell) replaces a single space with a double quote.  It should be replaced by the simpler sed command `y/ /"/`. (This does not address the issue you are having; merely pointing out the oft ignored `y` command.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/[^[:space:]]*/"&"/g' file > newfile
sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+/"&"/g' file > newfile
```

In the first POSIX BRE pattern, `[^[:space:]]*` matches zero or more chars other than whitespace chars and `"&"` replaces the match with itself enclosed with double quotes. In the first POSIX ERE pattern, `[^[:space:]]+` matches one or more chars other than whitespace.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/AvWsry):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="word1 word2 hello world"
sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+/"&"/g' <<< "$s"
# => "word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
sed 's/[^[:space:]]*/"&"/g' <<< "$s"
# => "word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure bash solution using `printf` that doesn't require any regex or external tool:

```sh
s="word1 word2 hello world"
set -f
printf -v r '"%s" ' $s
set +f

echo "$r"
"word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
```

PS: Use `echo "${r% }"` is you want to remove trailing space.

Comment: The output would be surprising if the string contains globbing characters. It is better to disable the glob by `set -f` (or an equivalent command) for this to work properly.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin that's a great suggestion it is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "word1 word2 hello world" | sed 's/\S\+/"&"/g'
"word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\S` (not sure about `\+`)

Answer (score 1):

Given this string stored in a variable named `instr`:

```
$ instr='word1 word2 hello world'
```

You could do:

```
$ read -r -a array <<< "$instr"
$ printf -v outstr '"%s" ' "${array[@]}"
$ echo "${outstr% }"
"word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ echo "$instr" | awk -v OFS='" "' '{$1=$1; print "\"" $0 "\""}'
"word1" "word2" "hello" "world"
```